# Find the inverse of $|y|^p-|y|=x$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

I'm trying to find a way to compute the inverse of $|y|^p-|y|=x$, I can try my best to compute this numerically, but I was wondering if there was any analytical way to determine this particular inverse. The problem does have any motivation beyond just regular curiosity.

EDIT: Since the function is not one-to-one, how would I go about finding the inverse on each segment of the function that is one-to-one? So for the intervals:
$$
\left(-\infty, -\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/(p-1)}\right)\\
\left(-\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/(p-1)}, 0\right)\\
\left(0, \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/(p-1)}\right)\\
\left(\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/(p-1)}, \infty\right)
$$

Comment: This equation does not define a function since $(0,-1),(0,1) \in \{(x,y): |y|^p-|y|=x\}$

Comment: Hi, the problem was ill stated. I've edited it hopefully to give some more clarity.